# Adding rows to database based on selected checkbox and quantities - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

My script selects a list of items from a db table and presents them alongside a checkbox. If the checkbox is checked and the form is submitted, that item is added into the 'stock' table.

I have had to make an adjustment so that the user can select a checkbox and also chose a quantity. However, I am not using 'quantity' as a value to be inserted into a row. Instead, if a user selects a quantity of 3 for stock item 'Apple', I would want 3 rows of Apple to be added to the database. My current HTML script (wrapped in a while loop):

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $show3['Part_Type']; ?>,<?php echo $show3['Sub_Type']; ?>" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]" />
<?php echo $show3['Sub_Type']; ?><input type="number" size="2" value="1" name="qty_<?php echo $show3['Sub_Type']; ?>"></label>
```

The script for posting to the db:

```
foreach ($_POST['cbg1'] as $stock) {
  $lst = explode(",", $stock); 
  //I do this because I send two values through the checkbox separated by a comma

  $query = ("INSERT INTO stock SET Item_Specifics_Type='$lst[0]',
  Item_Specifics_SubType='$lst[1]',
  colour = '$colour',
  additional='$additional',
  stock_item = '$Make $ModelName $lst[1]'
  ");
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Edit to the script following answer:

```
foreach ($_POST['cbg1'] as $stock) {


list($partType,$subType) = explode(",", $stock); 

$query = ("INSERT INTO stock SET
StockID='$unique_id-$breaker-$i',
unique_id='$breaker-$unique_id',
VehicleID='$unique_id',
breaker='$breaker',
Make='$Make',
Model='$Model',
Year='$Year',
YearRange='$year_range_array',
fuel= '$fuel',
enginesize = '$engine',
Item_Specifics_Type='$partType',
Item_Specifics_SubType='$subType',
colour = '$colour',
value = '$value',
vin='$vin',
additional='$additional',
stock_item = '$Make $ModelName $subType',
icp ='1',
upload_date ='$now'");

for($i=0;$i<$_POST['qty_'.$subType];$i++){
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}

}
```

Comment: Checkbox doesn't transmit values. It transmits ON or doesn't even transmit.

Comment: There are a lot of error checking and vulnerabilities in this code, but putting that aside, once you've got the values of `$lst` you probably want to check the values of `$_POST['qty_' . $lst[1]]` and loop your sql `for $i = 0; $i < intval($_POST['qty_' . $lst[1]]); $i++) { // sql }` times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there... But beware, your code needs to be reviewed for security as there are many flaws to it. I'll assume it is for prototyping, and continue on with the logic to add.

```
foreach ($_POST['cbg1'] as $stock) {
  list($partType,$subType) = explode(",", $stock); 
  //I do this because I send two values through the check box separated by a comma
  $query = ("INSERT INTO stock SET Item_Specifics_Type='$partType',
       Item_Specifics_SubType='$subType',
       colour = '$colour',
       additional='$additional',
       stock_item = '$Make $ModelName $subType'
  ");
  for($i=0;$i<$_POST['qty_'.$subType];$i++){
      $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
   }
}
```

So what we do is loop through the quantity amount stated in the qty input to add the multiple rows.

I've also used list() with the explode to make two distinct variables this will make reading easier for others or when the code grows as they now are explicitly telling what they contain.

Comment: Thanks @Salketer, I have updated my question to show the full extent of the query (few extra cols being added to the database now) and with your adjusted list() and for loop (am I right in thinking $_POST['qty_'.$lst[1]] should be $_POST['qty_'.$subType] now we have used list()?) However I am not getting a POST at all now...

Comment: @tomantford Yes, sorry I fixed the answer. In your updated query, there are a lot of variables added, but this should not pose any problem... What exactly is the problem now? I'm guessing it is the unique_id? Can you show me the indexes of that table please?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the loop doesn't run to trigger the mysql_query. Whilst looping through the $subType I would expect for example the first post to be: `<label><input checked="" type="checkbox" value="Accident &amp; Breakdown,Accident Accessories" class="cbgroup1" name="cbg1[]">Accident Accessories<input type="number" size="2" value="1" name="qty_Accident Accessories"></label>`

Comment: the problem here is the space... do a var_dump of $_POST, you will understand.

Comment: Ahh I see! I thought that could be the case as I was inspecting it. Is there a way I can preserve the space using url encode perhaps?

Comment: ignore me, instead i'll send the unique ID from the database for the checkbox!

Comment: when I perform the loop I want to send a unique value each time the mysql_query is ran so that if for example two apples are uploaded, they will be inserted with the id as `unique_id='$breaker-$unique_id-$x'` where $x would be the increment i.e 1-UNIQUEID-1 and 1-UNIQUEID-2

Comment: You could use $i from the for loop, ($i+1 if you don't want 0). But that will not guarantee uniqueness if the user submits the form twice. What you want here is maybe a simple auto_increment index in your table, that mySQL will take care by its own... That way every single line will have a different ID. It is easy to concatenate with your uniqueid if need be, but I do not understand why you need this kind of ID to start with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70717/discussion-between-tomantford-and-salketer).